# Implementing a safe access container

Tags: c#, properties

Assume I have some class that represents a container. That container holds some public properties with get and set modifiers.

What I want is to implement some mechanism that will enable access and disable access to these properties reference at runtime.

For example, when some boolean flag is true, you can access these properties. That means that:

```
SomeClass.Property1;
```

Will not generate an exception and will return the object.

However, when it is false, the above line of code will throw an exception.

It is of course possible to be done when using some boolean key, and checking it at the gateway to every property.

My question is, is it possible to implement such mechanism that will enfoce these limitations for all the properties in the class, **without the need to assert these conditions within every access to these properties.**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: so you want to check for something everytime you do something... _without the need to check for something everytime you do something?_

Comment: My question was not accurate enought I guess. What I intended is a mechanism that will automatically apply some global check wheneven accessing it's properties. I am not saying this is possible. But came across some dead end, and wanted to check if I missed something.

Comment: @Ohad you can try to look at [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or some other tool for weaving .NET assemblies.

Comment: Thank you, I will definetly look into that. Instead of using such tools, would it be possible to implement such module with another programming language and use that module with c# modules?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) might helps.

Simple code that shows how it can be used in your case. Not exactly the same as you want but it doesn't need to assert conditions with every access to object's properties and methods.

Entities:

```
abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
    public abstract void DoSomethingElse();

    public abstract int Property { get; set; }
}

class RealEntity : AbstractEntity
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something");
    }

    public override void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something else");
    }

    public override int Property { get; set; }
}

class NullEntity : AbstractEntity
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // do nothing or throw exception
    }

    public override void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // do nothing or throw exception
    }

    public override int Property
    {
        get { throw new Exception(); }
        set { throw new Exception(); }
    }
}
```

Simple example of AccessContainer:

```
class AccessContainer
{
    private RealEntity _entity = new RealEntity();
    private NullEntity _nullEntity = new NullEntity();

    private bool _access = true;

    public AbstractEntity Entity
    {
        get => _access ? (AbstractEntity) _entity : (AbstractEntity) _nullEntity;
    }

    public void OpenAccess()
    {
        _access = true;
    }

    public void DenyAccess()
    {
        _access = false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var container = new AccessContainer();

container.Entity.DoSomething(); // prints something
var prop = container.Entity.Property; // access to property

container.DenyAccess();
container.Entity.DoSomething(); // do nothing

container.OpenAccess();
container.Entity.DoSomething(); // prints something again

container.DenyAccess();
var prop2 = container.Entity.Property; // exception
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. Sadly this suggestion does not answer the needs I am facing at the moment. Few reasons why:
1. As you need to declare 3 classes just for one property, you need the implementor of such containers to do it right, instead of auto applying the wanted checks.
2. Seems like this design essentially implements the same outcome as if you were just checking access to the properties youself. This is because you need to throw an exception and implement the special case anyways.

Comment: The third reason and for me the most problematic, is that this code is hackable. You can easily "OpenAccess", then save that "real" entity in some local variable, and then "DenyAccess". From now on you can't access the container's entity, but you can still access the real saved entity, which is basically what I am trying to hide in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for doesn't natively exist, you're going to have to write some sort of wrapping functionality to test whether accessibility is granted.

```
public interface IAccessOwner {
    bool Accessible { get; } 
} 

[DebuggerDisplay("Accessible: {Accessible,nq} - Value: {ToString()}")]
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(RestrictedObject<>.DebuggerProxy))]
public class RestrictedObject<T> {
    private readonly IAccessOwner _owner;
    private T _value;

    public RestrictedObject(IAccessOwner owner, T initialValue) 
      : this(owner) {
       _value = initialValue;
    }
    public RestrictedObject(IAccessOwner owner) {
       _owner = owner ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(owner));
    } 

    public T Value {
       get {
          ThrowIfInaccessible();
          return _value;
       }
       set {
          ThrowIfInaccessible();
          _value = value;
       } 
    }

    public bool Accessible => _owner.Accessible;

    public override string ToString() {
       if (!Accessible)
          return "<Inaccessible>"; // ToString should never throw 
       if (_value is { } val) 
          return val.ToString();
       return "<null>";
    } 

    private void ThrowIfInaccessible() {
       if(!Accessible)
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Not accessible!");
    }

    // explicit operator to cast directly to value
    public static explicit operator T(RestrictedObject<T> ro) {
       ro.ThrowIfInaccessible();
       return ro.Value;
    }

    private sealed class DebuggerProxy {
       public bool Accessible { get; } 
       public T Value { get; } 
       public DebuggerProxy(RestrictedObject<T> ro) {
          bool acc = Accessible = ro.Accessible;
          if (acc) 
             Value = ro._value;
       } 
    } 
}
```

You can then use properties of this type in your class:

```
public class MyClass : IAccessOwner {
    private readonly RestrictedObject<int> _prop1;
    private readonly RestrictedObject<string> _prop2;

    public MyClass(int someVal) {
       _prop1 = new RestrictedObject<int>(this, someVal);
       _prop2 = new RestrictedObject<string>(this);
       Accessible = true;
    } 

    public bool Accessible { get; private set; } 
    // you determine how you want to toggle the above property. 
    // Exposing it publicly defeats the purpose of all of this, 
    // but for demo purposes only:
    public void DenyAccess() {
       Accessible = false;
    } 
    public void AllowAccess() {
       Accessible = true;
    }

    // these properties will throw exceptions if the owner 
    // (this object) is not currently accessible. 
    public int Prop1 {
       get => _prop1.Value;
       set => _prop1.Value = value;
    }
    public string Prop2 {
       get => _prop2.Value;
       set => _prop2.Value = value;
    } 

    // alternatively return the wrapper itself 
    // allowing you to control the accessibility 
    // even after returning the object 
    public RestrictedObject<string> AltProp2 => _prop2;

}
```

You would then use it like the following (obviously exceptions will halt the execution, handling has been elided):

```
var mc = new MyClass(3);

Console.WriteLine(mc.Prop1); // prints 3
Console.WriteLine(mc.Prop2); // prints null

var temp = mc.AltProp2; // use the wrapper directly

mc.Prop2 = "Hello";
Console.WriteLine(mc.Prop2); // prints Hello
Console.WriteLine(temp.Value); // prints Hello
Console.WriteLine((string)temp); // explicit operator, prints Hello

mc.DenyAccess();

mc.Prop1 = 33; // throws! 
Console.WriteLine(mc.Prop1); // throws! 
Console.WriteLine(mc.Prop2); // throws! 
Console.WriteLine(temp.Value); // throws! 
Console.WriteLine((string)temp); // explicit operator, throws!
Console.WriteLine(temp); // prints "<Inaccessible>" 

mc.AllowAccess();

string temp3 = (string)temp; // "Hello", explicit operator works again
mc.Prop1 = 22; // as do our setters 
mc.Prop2 = "Goodbye";

if (temp.Accessible) {
  Console.WriteLine(temp); // "Goodbye" 
}
```

The only thing that won't throw an exception is the override of `ToString` on the `RestrictedObject` type itself since you should never throw from `ToString`. Instead we just return `<Inaccessible>`.

We've also changed how the `RestrictedObject<T>` is displayed in a debugger via the `DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`. If someone tries to inspect the object's *properties* they will see the `Accessible` property and only if `true` will the wrapped object's `Value` appear. Otherwise, `default(T)` will be displayed (`null` for reference types, `0` for integral types and `false` for `bool`). Furthermore, through use of the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` we've customized the display of the *collapsed* version of our object such that it shows the `Accessible` property alongside our customized `ToString`.

Note that this still has the drawback that if someone retrieves the inner/wrapped object and accessibility has later been denied, they still have the object. There's nothing you are going to be able to do to really guard against that case. You must also realize (and accept) that anyone using reflection could alter or access the state of the object if they really wanted to.

I will also note that this violates normal C# practices, which *typically* dictate that properties should not throw exceptions. [Microsoft's own guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) say as much, though they use the term "Avoid" rather than "Do Not". The framework itself is guilty of violating this "rule". If you're going to violate the [principle of least surprise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment?wprov=sfla1), at the very least have the courtesy to **document this behavior** for consumers of your API.